# os.read() gives OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when reading large data

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I use the following method to read binary data from any given offset in the binary file. The binary file I have is huge 10GB, so I usually read portion of it when needed by specifying from which offset I should `start_read` and how many bytes to read `num_to_read`. I use `Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.`, platform `Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit` and [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) module:

```
def read_from_disk(path, start_read, num_to_read, dim):
    fd = os.open(path, os.O_RDONLY)
    os.lseek(fd, start_read, 0)  # Where to (start_read) from the beginning 0
    raw_data = os.read(fd, num_to_read)  # How many bytes to read
    C = np.frombuffer(raw_data, dtype=np.int64).reshape(-1, dim).astype(np.int8)
    os.close(fd)
    return C
```

This method works very well when the chunk of data to be read is about less than 2GB. When `num_to_read > 2GG`, I get this error:

```
raw_data = os.read(fd, num_to_read)  # How many to read (num_to_read)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I am not sure why this issue appears and how to fix it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: What build of Python are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you're using 32-bit software, you need 64-bit to access more than 2GB.

Comment: @abarnert Mac OSX.

Comment: @Barmar No, he's probably on a 64-bit platform, but using 32-bit file APIs.

Comment: @PeterWood `Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

Comment: @Barmar By running `import platform platform.platform()` I get `Darwin-17.6.0-x86_64-i386-64bit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`os.read` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/posixmodule.c#L8286) is just a thin wrapper around the platform's `read` function.

On some platforms, this is an unsigned or signed 32-bit int,<sup>1</sup> which means the largest you can `read` in a single go on these platforms is, respectively, 4GB or 2GB.

So, if you want to read more than that, and you want to be cross-platform, you have to write code to handle this, and to buffer up multiple `read`s.

This may be a bit of a pain, but you are intentionally using the lowest-level directly-mapping-to-the-OS-APIs function here. If you don't like that:

- Use `io` module objects (Python 3.x) or `file` objects (2.7) that you get back from `open` instead.
- Just let NumPy read the files—which will have the added advantage that NumPy is smart enough to not try to read the whole thing into memory at once in the first place.
- Or, for files this large, you may want to go lower level and use `mmap` (assuming you're on a 64-bit platform).

---

The right thing to do here is almost certainly a combination of the first two. In Python 3, it would look like this:

```
with open(path, 'rb', buffering=0) as f:
    f.seek(start_read)
    count = num_to_read // 8 # how many int64s to read
    return np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int64, count=count).reshape(-1, dim).astype(np.int8)
```

---

<sub>1. For Windows, the POSIX-emulation library's `_read` function uses `int` for the count argument, which is signed 32-bit. For every other modern platform, see POSIX [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html), and then look up the definitions of `size_t`, `ssize_t`, and `off_t`, on your platform. Notice that many POSIX platforms have separate 64-bit types, and corresponding functions, instead of changing the meaning of the existing types to 64-bit. Python will use the standard types, not the special 64-bit types.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your clear answer. How can I specify `num_to_read ` in your code? This is very important to me as I don't want to read all the file, just portion of it